# How can I scrape all content from each "option" of a "select" field of HTML with R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, selectnodes

I'm trying to use `rvest` package for web scraping an website.

This link will be used as an example: https://www.globalinnovationindex.org/analysis-indicator

The objective is to scrape the tables from all years (select id="ctl29_lstYear") and all indexes (select id="ctl29_lstIndex"). I already have a chunk that scrape and format thoose tables and turn them into lists (and yes... they are not an html `<table>`), but I can't use `follow_link()` or `set_values()` to navigate through the options of years and indexes, and scrape them all.

Let's use a single pair of "options" for this example (year="2013" and index=" Innovation Efficiency Ratio"):

So, I've looked at the `rvest::set_values()` documentation and I found this example:

```
    search <- html_form(read_html("http://www.google.com"))[[1]]
    set_values(search, q = "My little pony")
```

And then I tried this:

```
    > session<-html_form(read_html("https://www.globalinnovationindex.org/analysis-indicator"))[[1]]
    > set_values(session,list(ctl29$lstYear = "2013",ctl29$lstIndex="Innovation Efficiency Ratio"))
    Error: unexpected '=' in "set_values(session,list(ctl29$lstYear ="
```

Why it was unexpected the '=' after the name of the fields that I want to modify? Do the `set_values()` is the best option for this kind of problem?

Comment: R doesn't like the `$` to be used as the name of a list element. You'll need to properly escape that value. Try `set_values(session,list(\`ctl29$lstYear\` = "2013",\`ctl29$lstIndex\`="Innovation Efficiency Ratio"))`

Comment: @rafael did you notice that there are csv files available that (presumably) contain the data

Comment: @MrFlick i've tried what you posted, but the output doesn't seem to change. With the "My little pony" example, the first 'form' is `<input text> 'q': ` and after `set_values()`, is `<input text> 'q': My little pony`. Using your recomendation, the first and the last 'form' outputs, for both fields is the same: `<select> 'ctl29$lstYear' [1/6]` and `<select> 'ctl29$lstIndex' [1/112]`.

Comment: @AndrewLavers yes I did, but what I want to know is how to deal with the `<select>` tag when I'm scraping a web page.